# Fiware Orion in docker hangs

Tags: docker, docker-compose, fiware, fiware-orion

After some hours Orion stop responding

I am using the latest docker image in my Docker file (there are other services in the docker file):

```
 mongo:
    image: mongo:3.2
    hostname: mongo
    container_name: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    command: --nojournal
 orion:
    image: fiware/orion
    hostname: orion
    container_name: orion
    ports:
      - "1026:1026"
    mem_limit: 1g
    links:
      - mongo
    command: -dbhost mongo -logLevel INFO
```

My docker and docker-compose versions are:

```
Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4
docker-compose version 1.16.1, build 6d1ac21
```

Orion process is always here but not reponsing to HTTP requests:

```
[root@orion contextBroker]#  ps aux
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
root         1  0.0  0.2 732488 16660 ?        Ssl  Oct16   0:01 /usr/bin/contextBroker -fg -multiservice -dbhost mongo -logLevel INFO
root        59  0.0  0.0  11496  2652 pts/0    Ss   06:49   0:00 /bin/bash
root       192  0.0  0.0  13380  1832 pts/0    R+   07:15   0:00 ps aux
```

I check this link for [diagnosis](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/diagnosis/index.html)

- No problem on the disk availability
- file descriptors or socket exhaustion problem : no issue:
  [image]
- Diagnose memory exhaustion problem:

[image]

No errors have been displayed on the container logs.
And when I got inside the container **Orion can respond to the command line** "contextBroker --version"

And **if I want to restart the container I need to restart the docker service.**

Any idea how to solve this?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: Do you have success pinging the Orion instance? I just saw commands from inside the docker instance... however, you did not mention what kind of errors you are facing. Please edit your question explaining them. I think this can help someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [official docker compose file](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/docker/docker-compose.yml):

```
mongo:
  image: mongo:3.2
  command: --nojournal

orion:
  image: fiware/orion
  links:
    - mongo
  ports:
    - "1026:1026"
command: -dbhost mongo
```

It doesn't include any `mem_limit` field. I'm not an expert in docker compose, but I understand it probably caps the available available memory in the container. Just 1GB is very small for Orion, thus I'd recommend not using that field or at least increate to a higher limit (test with 2GB or 4GB to see how it goes).

Comment: thanks, I already had the problem without including the mem_limit and had it also with 2GB. I don't think it is a memory issue since I don't see that Orion uses a lot of memory (using cAdvisor)

Comment: And for information when I enter inside the container, Orion can respond to the command line "contextBroker --version"